# PHP and MYSQL Working even if xampp shows errors

Tags: php, mysql, server, xampp, localhost

i have a mistake somewhere with my xampp and i don't know what to do, this my 4th day looking for a solution. 
now, the server is working but in xampp tehre are few errors.

- [here the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjMgj.jpg)
- [Here for example phpMyAdmin run without any error, but xampp !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G35J.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you have existing instances running already.

Comment: when i click on start and errors shows up i notice that phpmyadmin is working even if xampp shows that the server won't start

Comment: What is process id# 2228?  ... you can get that from the task manager.  As @danblack already said, something already has those running. Either running standalone, or by something else.  For example, if mysql was already installed to the system before xampp was installed, xampp can use the previous existing instance without need to start xampp's copy. If you only desire to use xampp's specific versions, then you need to stop the other services. Are there 2 copies of xampp on the system, perhaps?

Comment: @PaulT. the PID is for httpd.exe and it's not displayed in the task manager (services) i get it from NetStat - TCP listening sockets
in task manager there is only httpd.exe and mysqld.exe mentioned in running processes and nthing about'em  in the services

Comment: The PID column is usually not displayed by default, but [it is there](http://i64.tinypic.com/moew9.jpg). You can right-click the columns to add other entries.